# rabbitmq stauck at Startup in progress

Tags: rabbitmq

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 and trying to install rabbitmq using the [Cloudsmith Quick Start Script](https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-debian.html#apt-quick-start-cloudsmith).

But after installation rabbitmq never starts. Its always stuck at Status: "Startup in progress".

When I try restarting, I get
rabbitmq-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

Is it not compatible with Ubuntu22.04?

Following is the journalctl log:

```
rabbitmq-server[14454]: BOOT FAILED
rabbitmq-server[14454]: 2023-11-14 16:17:39.188711+00:00 [error] <0.136.0>
rabbitmq-server[14454]: 2023-11-14 16:17:39.188711+00:00 [error] <0.136.0> BOOT FAILED
rabbitmq-server[14454]: 2023-11-14 16:17:39.188711+00:00 [error] <0.136.0> ===========
rabbitmq-server[14454]: 2023-11-14 16:17:39.188711+00:00 [error] <0.136.0> ERROR: epmd error for host phdfocus-server-2: timeout (timed out)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error log had the following line:

```
ERROR: epmd error for host phdfocus-server-2: timeout (timed out)
```

Timeout from epmd suggests a DNS issue. I checked the `/etc/hosts`. The server name was resolving to a wrong IP. I corrected it and rabbitmq started.